# Can't change the profile picture

Tags: support

I can't change my user picture. The current picture is taken from my private Facebook account.

When I go to my profile page on Stack Overflow, it is not editable. It has a small icon "Network Profile" that takes me to a Stack Exchange page that lets me edit my profile description, but not the picture.

Comment: Works for me. Go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/edit/12617758), and click on the "change picture" banner text at the bottom of your picture.